# How do I change the text of a label without overlapping?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, widget

This is part of my code:

```
def ifEnter():
    output_lab = StringVar()
    output_lab.set("Username: \nPassword: ")
    output_label = Label(top, textvariable=output_lab, wraplength=400, justify=LEFT)
    output_label.place(x = 40, y = 280)
    search = search_var.get()

    b = 0
    for i in mydict:
        if i == search:
            b = 1
            output_lab.set("Username: {}\nPassword: {}".format(mydict[i][0], mydict[i][1]))
    if b != 1:
        output_lab.set('There is no "%s" in your password manager.' % search)
```

It is supposed to display different Labels depending on the if statements, however If I press the button that displays the labels twice with a different label I get overlaps:

[image]

Comment: are you calling that function twice?

Comment: @TheLizzard Yes, I press the button twic and so the function is being called twice.

Comment: Well the problem is that each time you call it, it creates a new label and places it in the same location. Why don't you move the first 4 lines of the function and put them somewhere else? It should fix your problem

Comment: @TheLizzard I will get back to you and see if it works.